# AngularJS ng-change not functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have this Dropdown list in `$dialogScope.items` But I tried to call in function selectChange but it doesn't seems to be working. kindly help me notice the mistake

This is from the html part

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
 <label class="control-label">Type</label><br/>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
   <option value=""> Select Type</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

```
 $scope.addStep = function (patchID) {
    $dialog.open({
        showClose: false,
        closeByEscape: true,
        template: 'views/app-edit/app-edit-patch-step-add.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($dialogScope) {
            $dialogScope.items = [{
                name:"Download APK",
                value:"0",
            },{
                name:"Backup",
                value:"1"
            },{
                name:"Restore",
                value:"2",
            },{
                name:"Download OBB",
                value:"4",
            },{
                name: "Download OBB By GPU",
                options : ["Adreno","Mali","Tegra","PowerVR","Other"]
            },{
                name: "Download APK By GPU",
                options : ["Adreno","Mali","Tegra","PowerVR","Other"]
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE",
                value:"7",
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE By GPU",
                value:"8",
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE & Unzip After Install",
                value:"9",
            },{
                name: "Download CACHE By GPU & Unzip After Install",
                value:"10",
            },
            ];
            $dialogScope.hideMe = function(hideElements){
                if($dialogScope.selectedItem){
                    return (hideElements.indexOf($dialogScope.selectedItem.name) != -1)?false:true;
                }
                else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
            $dialogScope.selectChange = function(selectedItem){
                if (selectedItem.value) {
                    $dialogScope.type = selectedItem.value;
                    $dialogScope.labelA = 'dferfre';
                    $dialogScope.labelB = '';
                    $dialogScope.labelC = 'MD5';
                    $dialogScope.stepA = '';
                    $dialogScope.stepB = '';
                    $dialogScope.stepC = '';
                    if (value == 0) {
                         $dialogScope.labelA = "APK URL";
                     } else if (value == 4) {
                         $dialogScope.labelA = "OBB URL";
                     } else if (value == 5) {
                         $dialogScope.labelB = "OBB URL";
                     } else if (value = 6) {
                         $dialogScope.labelB = "APK URL";
                     }


                    $dialogScope.$apply();
                }
            };
```

Comment: What is `$dialogScope` ? Please provide the code of controller function parameter

Comment: You didn't pass anything in `selectChange()` call in your ng-change

Comment: @PrinceG That shouldn't be the issue . It doesn't matter .

Comment: @PrinceG i am new to angularJs. can u provide me example?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi kindly see my update and could u please tell me what is wrong with my codes

Comment: @sue ui can't access `$dialogScope` . It'll be better if you can provide me a JSfiddle link

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi i dont think  `$dialogScope` is the problem because $dialogScope.hideMe working just fine

Answer (score 1):

You should change $dialogScope.selectChange to $scope.selectChange and you also forgot to pass the variable to function from ur html. Personally I would prefer to use controllerAs syntax.

Instead of having inline controller function. Create separate controller "MyDialogController" file then replace ur html with the following html.

```
<div ng-controller="MyDialogController" class="form-group has-feedback">
 <label class="control-label">Type</label><br/>
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
   <option value=""> Select Type</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What if he injected `$scope` and mapped with `$dialogScope` ?

Comment: I am going with the assumption that he hasn't and I think ur asking for the same thing in ur previous comment :)

Comment: @AtulChaudhary can u provide me example?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the model into your function. Try this.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="selectChange(selectedItem)" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
```